# Use of Pointers in a separate function file

Tags: c, function, pointers, gcc

Working of Pointers

```
// swap.h

swap(int, int);

// swap.c

swap(int *i, int *j)
{
  int k;
  k=*i;
  *i=*j;
  *j=k;
}

// Practice.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "swap.h"

main()
{   
  int i,j;

  printf("\nEnter I = ");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("\nEnter J = ");
  scanf("%d",&j);

  swap(&i, &j);

  printf("\n I = %d",i);
  printf("\n J = %d",j);
}
```

When I wrote this program in one file, the program was correctly executed. Now after I divided it into 2 parts, `Practice.c` that has `main()` function and `swap.c` that contains the `swap(int *i, int *j)` function, it did not go so well.
Here is the following process I used to execute the program.

```
gcc -c swap.c
gcc Practice.c swap.o -oPractice
```

As soon as I tried to execute the 2nd statement it did not compile and produced errors.

I used exactly the same process for executing another program, which had 3 files,

1. Practice.c { main() function }
2. Add.c { add() function }
3. Add.h { header file }

It did not have pointers.

Please tell me where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: This question has terrible formatting and lacks information (the error). Please rewrite and reformat it.

Comment: What error it is producing?

Comment: Your prototype for `swap()` is wrong; you claim it takes `int` but it really takes `int *` (for both parameters). This will be a problem if your system has a different size for `int` vs pointers.

Comment: Always ask the compiler to warn you (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and always respect the warnings the compiler's gives you.

Comment: @MarcoA. reformatting done.

Comment: Following were the errors -
`
Warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   swap(&i,&j);
   ^
In file included from Practice.c:2:0:
swap.h:1:5: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'
 int swap(int ,int);
     ^
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `swap.h` change

```
swap(int, int);
```

to

```
swap(int *, int *);
```

Your `swap` function takes integer pointers as parameters, but your declaration says to take integers. So compiler will give you errors.